# How are interface types loaded by the CLR?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, clr, method-dispatch

Does the CLR Load interface types if they are not initialized with Concrete implementations?

Considering an interface IFoo which has an implementation FooImpl

e.g.

```
IFoo foo;
```

as opposed to

```
IFoo foo = new FooImpl();
```

Will the CLR only load the IFoo Type in the second case? Also if there is a another type which inherits from FooImpl (e.g. FooImpl2)

Will this code start from FooImpl2 and walk up the inheritance hierarchy to load IFoo interface? Also, will the IFoo's MethodTable contain a pointer directly to the FooImpl2's method table or will it redirected via the intermediate implementing type (ie FooImpl).

```
IFoo foo = new FooImpl2();
```

Comment: Nothing very subtle happens, stubs in the CLR are an iceberg that is 99% under water.  Vance Morrison explains it well in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/03/13/550529.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks for sharing the post, will go through it! I remember you used to moderate the MSDN forums back in 2009..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code

```
IFoo foo;
```

says that the `foo` is a variable that can hold a reference to an object that implements the interface `IFoo`.

> Will the CLR only load the IFoo Type in the second case?

In the second case you create an object of type `FooImpl` and you make use of a variable called `foo` that stores a reference to this object. In order for a variable to hold a reference to an object, the variable's type should be compliant to this object. Saying compliant, I mean that either the variable's type would be the same as the object you create or would be a base type or an interface. That being said there isn't any load of any interface.

This line of code:

```
IFoo foo = new FooImpl();
```

says that the `foo` will hold a reference to an object that implements the `IFoo` interface, just this.

> Also if there is a another type which inherits from FooImpl (e.g.
>   FooImpl2) Will this code start from FooImpl2 and walk up the
>   inheritance hierarchy to load IFoo interface?

No

> Also, will the IFoo's MethodTable contain a pointer directly to the
>   FooImpl2's method table or will it redirected via the intermediate
>   implementing type (ie FooImpl).

The reference that will be stored in the variable would point to the FooImpl2's method table direclty. Actually, it would point to the concrete object stored in heap and there would be the reference to the method's table of `FooImpl2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

In the  IFoo foo = new FooImpl2 case, does the CLR see the IFoo type and then redirect the call to the Actual implementation using the SlotMap. Or does the CLR see an object of FooImpl2 and not the interface?

Comment: @ganeshran you are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :). The CLR does see a reference assignment. That you can assign to the left operand should implement the `IFoo`  type. Just this. By the way the most detailed book on this subject is Jeffrey's Richter, CLR via C#, http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Edition-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454.